Creating a dataframe from a column
I have a dataframe df which has a column prediction in it. The column prediction has values which are list of dictionaries. A typical row of the column prediction looks like this :
[{'answer': 'My name is Andrew.',
  'text': 'What is your name ?',
  'id': 1},
 {'answer': 'I live at California.',
  'text': 'Where do you live ?',
  'id': 2},
 {'answer': 'I want to become a doctor.',
  'text': 'What do you want to do ?',
  'id': 3}]


I want to convert the column prediction into a separate dataframe that will have the values of the key text as the column names and answer as the rows. Example :
What is your name ?      Where do you live?        What do you want to do?   
My name is Andrew        I live at California      I want to become a doctor.
My name is Julie         I live at NY              I want to be a cook.


Please suggest ways to do that.

Use nested list comprehension with DataFrame constructor:
L = [{'answer': 'My name is Andrew.',
  'text': 'What is your name ?',
  'id': 1},
 {'answer': 'I live at California.',
  'text': 'Where do you live ?',
  'id': 2},
 {'answer': 'I want to become a doctor.',
  'text': 'What do you want to do ?',
  'id': 3}]

df = pd.DataFrame({'prediction':[L, L, L]})


out = pd.DataFrame([{x['text']:x['answer'] for x in L} for L in df['prediction']])
print (out)
  What is your name ?    Where do you live ?    What do you want to do ?
0  My name is Andrew.  I live at California.  I want to become a doctor.
1  My name is Andrew.  I live at California.  I want to become a doctor.
2  My name is Andrew.  I live at California.  I want to become a doctor.


It looks like a use case for pd.json_normalize:
out = pd.json_normalize(df['prediction'])

Or pd.DataFrame.from_records:
out = pd.DataFrame.from_records(df['prediction'])

Output:
                       answer                      text  id
0          My name is Andrew.       What is your name ?   1
1       I live at California.       Where do you live ?   2
2  I want to become a doctor.  What do you want to do ?   3

Used input:
df = pd.DataFrame({'prediction': [{'answer': 'My name is Andrew.',
                                   'text': 'What is your name ?',
                                   'id': 1},
                                  {'answer': 'I live at California.',
                                   'text': 'Where do you live ?',
                                   'id': 2},
                                  {'answer': 'I want to become a doctor.',
                                   'text': 'What do you want to do ?',
                                   'id': 3}]})

Then if you want to reshape, you can pivot:
out = (pd.DataFrame.from_records(df['prediction'])
         .pivot(index='id', columns='text', values='answer')
       )


If you have a list in each cell, you can explode, convert to DataFrame, then pivot:
s = df['prediction'].explode()
out = (pd.DataFrame.from_records(s.tolist(), index=s.index)
         .pivot(columns='text', values='answer')
      )

Output:
        What do you want to do ? What is your name ?    Where do you live ?
0     I want to become a doctor.  My name is Andrew.  I live at California.

Used input:
df = pd.DataFrame({'prediction': [[{'answer': 'My name is Andrew.',
                                   'text': 'What is your name ?',
                                   'id': 1},
                                  {'answer': 'I live at California.',
                                   'text': 'Where do you live ?',
                                   'id': 2},
                                  {'answer': 'I want to become a doctor.',
                                   'text': 'What do you want to do ?',
                                   'id': 3}]]})

